# No thermostat, but still running hot

Tags: cooling-system, cooling

Have a 2001 Mitsubishi eclipse.

The thermostat was taken out but the car is still running hot.

I've checked the coolant level and it's full. Don't know what else to do.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are your hoses in good health? If they are very squishy you may need/want to replace them for starters.

Comment: Yes they are in good shape

Comment: Have you checked that the pump is moving fluid? Probably remove and inspect...

Comment: Did you try anything like bars leaks before to solve a previous issue? It could have messed with your coolant by making it gum up (if you didn’t replace it after using the bars)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment made 2 hours ago, have the pump checked. The vanes can corrode and disappear or the impeller just spin freely on the shaft, so while its drive pulley rotates the impeller does not move the fluid.

Other things to check are the radiator : is it blocked internally? can you get it flow tested?

Is the radiator blocked by leaves or paper / rubbish behind the grill / bumper - if air can't get freely to the radiator it won't cool the fluid.

Are the fans working? do the electrical fans come on when it gets too hot? If not, then there may be a faulty switch or faulty supply (fuse or relay) or faulty fan...

Comment: I don’t know if there are any standardized GPM ratings for these radiators, but if there are then it should be pretty easy to test the radiators flow rate.

Comment: @kyle_engineer the core will probably be capable of a flow rate (L/s or GPM) that is greater than what the engine will need - it's more about if it is blocked and not flowing enough...

Comment: For sure. My reasoning is that if there is a standard rate, say 6 GPM with no added pressure (e.g. gravity only) then one could fairly easily time 1 gallon and any time greater than 10 seconds would indicate some radiator blockage. However, if the radiator doesn’t have a tested/marked flow rate, then it would be hard to measure the flow efficiency. Not sure if you get where I’m coming from. Not a criticism or anything on your answer, just something it made me think about. :)

Comment: I seem to remember that the flow rate is specified per row & length and also by the amount of heat - but that depends on a specified temperature difference...

Comment: So it’s probably not as straightforward and simple as one would like... :/ oh well. I suppose there is still taking it to a shop if simple diagnosis fails. But just to be clear I 100% agree with your answer!

Comment: I suppose that’s true... damned thermodynamics!

Comment: One way to test the flow is to disconnect the upper radiator hose and start the car. It should pump lots out. If not, you've narrowed down you problem

Answer (score 0):

You're saying the fluid level is good, so that pretty much leaves either a defective water pump, or a clog in the radiator.  Either way, you will need to take it to a professional to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

With an overheating condition, I always start with a chemical test to check for combustion gasses in the cooling system.  Head gaskets are a big job, and although there are times when it is the cause of running hot, there are times when it becomes a victim of overheating from something else.  Either way, a bad headgasket is a game changer for many people, and it should be verified as early as possible before spending unnecessary time and money.